Solve $x^{2}+4\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor+2=0$?
Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional Part of $x.$
How to find the values of $x$ that satisfy the condition $$x^{2}+4\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor+2=0$$
My approach is bit difficult, and I am not sure about it.
We know that
$$\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor=x-\{x\}$$
Therefore the above equation can be re-written as
$$x^{2}+4(x-\{x\})+2=0$$
$$\implies x^{2}+4x+2=4\{x\}$$
Now we all know that
$$0\leq \{x\}<1$$
$$\implies 0\leq 4\{x\}<4$$
Which implies that $$0\leq (x^{2}+4x+2)<4$$
$$\implies 0\leq (x+2)^{2}-2<4$$
$$\implies 2\leq (x+2)^{2}<6$$
From this we will get the possible values of $x$ that satisfy the above inequality.
But I can't understand that how to get the exact values of $x$ that satisfy the given condition ?

You may find it helpful: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E%7B2%7D%2B4%5Cleft%5Clfloor%7Bx%7D%5Cright%5Crfloor%2B2%3D0%24&p=1

Use that $x^2+2$ is an integer divisible by 4.


The only solutions are in $x\le 0$.
Since $4\lfloor x \rfloor +2$ is always an integer, the only solutions are where $x^2$ is also an integer.
$x^2$ has to be $2$ modulo $4$, so in particular, $x$ cannot be an integer because any perfect square is $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$.

Based on these observations, we try $x = -\sqrt{4n+2}$ for $n=0,1,\ldots$. It is easy to check that only $-\sqrt{14}$ and $-\sqrt{18}$ work. This is confirmed by the plot below.


The only thing lacking here is a lower bound for solutions.

@md2perpe You are right, but the OP already derived lower and upper bounds. I was only trying to explain how to pin point the roots within this range using some simple observations.

You can calculate the solution directly as follows:
Note that $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is constant on the interval $[\lfloor x\rfloor , \lfloor x\rfloor +1)$.
We have
$$x^2 = -2-4\lfloor x\rfloor \geq 0 \Rightarrow \lfloor x\rfloor \leq -\frac 12\Rightarrow \lfloor x\rfloor \leq -1$$
Now, write
$$[x] = -n \text{ with } n \text{ natural}$$
For a solution to exist, the following two inequalities must be satisfied:
$$[x] = -n \stackrel{(1)}{\leq} -\sqrt{4n-2} \stackrel{(2)}{<} -n + 1 = [x] +1$$
Solving (1) and (2) gives:
$(1):\: n\geq 2+\sqrt 2 \Rightarrow \boxed{n \geq 4}$
$(2):\: 3-\sqrt 6<n<3+\sqrt 6 \Rightarrow \boxed{n \leq 5}$
So, you get the two solutions:
$n=4 \rightarrow \boxed{x= -\sqrt{14}}$
$n=5 \rightarrow \boxed{x= -\sqrt{18}}$


$$x^{2}+4\left\lfloor{x}\right\rfloor+2=0$$

Alternative approach:
$x = P + r ~: ~P \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq r < 1.$
Therefore,
$$P^2 + 2Pr + r^2 + 4P + 2 = 0 \implies $$
$$r^2 + r(2P) + P^2 + 4P + 2 = 0 \implies $$
$$r = \frac{1}{2} ~\left[ -2P ~ \pm \sqrt{ ~4P^2 - 4(P^2 + 4P + 2) ~}  ~\right] \implies $$
$$r = \frac{1}{2} ~\left[ -2P ~ \pm \sqrt{ -16P - 8  ~}  ~\right]$$
$$= -P \pm \sqrt{-4P - 2}. \tag1 $$

Since $~-4P - 2~$ is under a square root radical, you must have that 
$-4P - 2 \geq 0 \implies 4P + 2 \leq 0 \implies $ 
$P \leq \dfrac{-2}{4} \implies P \leq -1.$
You also have that $~0 \leq r < 1.$ 
Therefore, $~0 \leq -P \pm \sqrt{-4P - 2} < 1.$ 
Therefore, $~r ~$ can not equal 
$-P + \sqrt{-4P - 2}.$ 
Therefore,
$~0 \leq r =  -P - \sqrt{-4P - 2} < 1. \tag2$

Since the posted question carries the calculus tag, I will indulge in taking a derivative.
For $~P \leq -1,~$ let $~f(P)~$ denote $~-P - \sqrt{-4P - 2} \implies $
$$f'(P) = -1 + \frac{2}{\sqrt{-4P - 2}}.$$
Therefore, $~f(-1) < 0~$ and $~f(P)~$ is strictly decreasing on $~\Bbb{Z_{\leq -2}}.$
Further, by inspection,
$$~f(-3) < 0, ~0 < ~f(-4), ~f(-5) < 1, ~f(-6) > 1.$$
Then:
$$P = -4 \implies r = 4 - \sqrt{14} \implies P + r = -\sqrt{14}.$$
$$P = -5 \implies r = 5 - \sqrt{18} \implies P + r = -\sqrt{18}.$$

I will do similarly with what you did, but a little differently.
Let
$n=\lfloor{x}\rfloor$, $y=x-\lfloor{x}\rfloor$
then
$x=n+y$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $y\in[0,1)$
$$\\$$
Now,
$x^2+4\lfloor{x}\rfloor+2=(y+n)^2+4n+2=0$
$n\le-1\,$, because $\,4n+2\le0$
$f(y)=(y+n)^2+4n+2\,$ monotonically decreases for $y\in[0,1)$
Therefore $f(0)\ge0$ and $f(1)<0$
$$\\$$
$f(0)=n^2+4n+2=(n+2)^2-2\ge0\Rightarrow n\le-4$
$f(1)=n^2+6n+3=(n+3)^2-6<0\Rightarrow n\ge-5$
Thus, $n=-5$ or $n=-4$
$$\\$$
For $n=-5$, $\,x^2+4\lfloor{x}\rfloor+2=x^2-18=0\Rightarrow x=-3\sqrt2$
For $n=-4$, $\,x^2+4\lfloor{x}\rfloor+2=x^2-14=0\Rightarrow x=-\sqrt{14}$
$$\\$$
So the solutions are $\{-3\sqrt2,\,-\sqrt{14}\}$

Here is my solution:
Clearly, $\lfloor x\rfloor=-n\in \Bbb Z^{-}.$ Hence, we have $x=\sqrt{4n-2}$,
$$-n\leq \sqrt{4n-2}<-(n-1),$$
$$(n-1)^2<4n-2\leq n^2,$$
$$n^2-6n+3<0\leq n^2-4n+2.$$
The solution set is
$$S=\Bbb Z^{+}\cap(3-\sqrt6,3+\sqrt6)\cap[(-\infty,2-\sqrt3]\cup(2+\sqrt3,\infty)]=\{4,5\}.$$

We know that $x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\leq x$
$\Rightarrow x-1<-\left(\frac{x^2+2}{4}\right)\leq x$
Solving gives $x\in(-2-\sqrt6,-2-\sqrt2]\cup[-2+\sqrt2,\sqrt6-2)$
So, $\lfloor x\rfloor\in\{-5,-4\}$
If $\lfloor x\rfloor=-5$ then $x=-\sqrt{-4\lfloor x\rfloor-2}=-3\sqrt2$
If $\lfloor x\rfloor=-4$ then $x=-\sqrt{-4\lfloor x\rfloor-2}=-\sqrt{14}$
$\Rightarrow x\in\{-3\sqrt2,-\sqrt{14}\}$
